# Show null values ​in CASE + SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, conditional-statements, case

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TESTING](
    [ID] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [TYPE] [nvarchar] (1) NULL,
    [TIME] [int] NULL
```

and with the following data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TESTING]
           ([ID]
           ,[TYPE]
           ,[TIME])
     VALUES
('A1','1',3),
('A1','1',6),
('A2','2',8),
('A2','2',9),
('B1','1',2),
('B1','1',6),
('B2','2',4),
('B2','2',8),
('B2','2',11),
('B2','2',12)
```

What I want to do is this. I want to create a column that receives the value "<= 5" If **TIME** is less than or equal to 5 or "> 5" if the **TIME** is greater than 5.

then I put the following statement:

```
select ID,  TYPE, 
(case when TIME <= 5 then '<= 5' 
when TIME > 5 then '> 5' 
else 'OTHER' end) AS CONDITION, 
SUM(TIME) TOTAL 
from [dbo].[TESTANDO] 
GROUP BY ID, TYPE,
(case when TIME <= 5 then '<= 5' 
when TIME > 5 then '> 5' 
else 'OTHER' end)
```

Result:

[image]

I would like that in addition to the data that appeared, if there are values ​​in which "<= 5 or> 5" do not have values ​​the line I come with **TOTAL** 0. In the example I do not have lines from group A2 that meet condition "<= 5" which should appear in the result with the column **TOTAL** = 0

like this:

[image]

Comment: Please show your desired results as a text table in the question and be sure that they correspond to the data you have provided.

Comment: Modified Gordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` and aggregation to fill in the values:

```
select i.id, i.type, c.condition, coalesce(sum(time), 0) as total
from (select distinct id, type from testing) i cross join
     (values ('<= 5'), ('> 5')) c(condition) left join
     testing t
     on t.id = i.id and
        t.type = i.type and
        ((condition = '<= 5' and time <= 5) or
         (condition = '> 5' and time > 5)
        )
group by i.id, i.type, c.condition
order by i.id, i.type, c.condition;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=12a655a25a31ca9997772ed13cd34e58) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Excellent Gordon thanks! Just one thing, if i wanna put a where, it's a problem? Like.. Where Type = 1

Comment: @ClaytonTosatti . . . Put the condition in the subquery for `i`.